# Spree creating admin account ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, admin, spree

I been searching for couple days and i don't come up with the solution. I am new to ruby, but i want to develop my own online store by using spree.

I use:rails: Rails 3.2.13
ruby: ruby-1.9.3-p429
RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.24

my Gemfile is te following:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.13'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'sqlite3'

group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem 'pry-rails'
end

group :production do
  gem 'thin'
  gem 'pg'
end

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'shoulda'
end


gem 'spree'
gem 'spree_auth_devise', :github => "spree/spree_auth_devise"
gem 'spree_core', :github => "spree/spree", :branch => "master"
gem 'spree_frontend', :github => "spree/spree", :branch => "master"
gem 'spree_backend', :github => "spree/spree", :branch => "master"
gem 'spree_api', :github => "spree/spree", :branch => "master"
gem 'pry'

gem 'jquery-rails'


# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'debugger'
```

And I use the following commands:

bundle install
rails g spree:install
rails s

By doing In that way, I have the spree default store with the login menu...but I can't log in..AND I NEVER CREATE A USER...I saw that by executing rake spree_auth:admin:create
after rails g spree:install...it should create an admin user...but no idea...Any help?

Answer (score 4):

Create Spree admin account  from terminal :

```
rake spree_auth:admin:create
```

Want to create admin user for production mode:

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake spree_auth:admin:create
```

if you want to use default admin account(spree@example.com, spree@123)then just keep pressing **ENTER**, which will create the default spree admin account for you!

Answer (score 0):

If you run this command, you will be prompted for an email address and password for the admin user.

```
rake db:seed
```